# problemas para llenar una variable

Tags: javascript, json, array

Extraigo datos de un json, y en el bucle de lectura extraigo un dato de ese json y lo guardo en una variable, sin embargo la variable se queda vacía, adjunto el código con el ejemplo de un string y un array...

```js
url="http://localhost/appbd/json_recorridos.php";
filtraDestino(url);
 
function filtraDestino(url){
 var d="A ";
 $.getJSON(url,function(result){ 
  $.each(result, function(i, field){ 
   d += field.destino+" "; //destino es una propiedad del objeto json
  });
 });
 console.log(d); //esto me da como resultado solamente "A "
}

//en el caso de que la variable fuera un array el resultado es el mismo

function filtraDestino(url){
 var d= [];
 $.getJSON(url,function(result){ 
  $.each(result, function(i, field){ 
   d.push(field.destino);
  });
 });
 console.log(d); //esto me muestra los elementos del array
 console.log(d.length); //sin embargo esto me da 0
}
```